# What is the show/movie about a girl who travels forward in her future via a house found in the woods?

Tags: story-identification

I saw a movie or show back in the 80's when I was young that I cannot remember.

It is about a young girl that I think is at a family reunion or maybe vacation and wanders off into the woods/forest and stumbles upon a house that when she comes out of the woods/forest so many years have passed and her parents are really old but she did not age. I am not sure if she went into the house or not.

If anyone has any hints as to what it was I would be greatly happy. I don't know any of the characters in the film.

Comment: Live-action or cartoon? What language was it in? What country did you see it in? Can you describe any of the characters? Di did it seem to be a feature theatrical release, or a made-for-tv production? Did it seem aimed at any particular age group? Did it have any sort of overt tone (horror, sci-fi, mystery, etc)? Even small details may help us find this for you.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the movie! I believe it is *Tuck Everlasting* (2002) and this is [the website](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0283084/plotsummary/) I found it on.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe how this matches the question?  It doesn't seem that Winnie lives out of normal time at all.